# The program works wrong. It cannot load two xml file?

Tags: powershell

**The program works wrong.
 It cannot load two xml file?**

```
C: \program> powershell.exe -noexit .\1.ps1 chpercent -Path1 c:\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml -Path2 c:\program\MIK_AutoPremium.xml
Get-Content: Cannot bind the argument to the "Path" parameter because it is an empty string.
C:\program\1.ps1: 20 character: 42+ $inputpecentw1.Text = [xml] (Get-Content $Path1) | ForEach-Object {$ ...+ ~~~~~~+ CategoryInfo: InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException+FullyQualifiedErrorId: ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Get-Content: Cannot bind the argument to the "Path" parameter because it is an empty string.
C:\program\1.ps1: 21 character: 49+ $inputpecentw2.Text = [xml] (Get-Content $ Path2) | ForEach-Obj ...+ ~~~~~~+ CategoryInfo: InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException+FullyQualifiedErrorId: ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentComman
```

**the program that does not work right.**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    function chpecent {
    param(
      [string]$Path1,
      [string]$Path2
    )
    $form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
    $textnamef1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
    $textnamef2 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
    $textPercent = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
        $inputpecentw1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
        $inputpecentw2 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
        $Read = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
        $Save = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
        $form1_Load = {
     $inputpecentw1.Text = [xml](Get-Content $Path1) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
            $inputpecentw2.Text = [xml](Get-Content $Path2) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
        }    
        $Read_Click = {
            #press read button
          $inputpecentw1.Text = [xml](Get-Content $Path1) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
            $inputpecentw2.Text = [xml](Get-Content $Path2) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
             }
        $Save_Click = {
            #press save button
             $new_value1 = $inputpecentw1.Text
             $new_value2 = $inputpecentw2.Text
            [xml](Get-Content $Path1)  | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.SetAttribute("Percent", $new_value1) }; $_.Save($Path1) }
            [xml](Get-Content $Path2)  | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.SetAttribute("Percent", $new_value2) }; $_.Save($Path2) }
          } 
         $form1.Controls.Add($textnamef1)
         $form1.Controls.Add($textnamef2)
        $form1.Controls.Add($inputpecentw1)
        $form1.Controls.Add($inputpecentw2)
            $form1.Controls.Add($Read)
        $form1.Controls.Add($Save)
        $form1.ClientSize = '800, 800'
        $form1.Text = 'проценты'
        $form1.add_Load($form1_Load)
        $textnamef1.AutoSize = $True
        $textnamef1.Location = '80, 40'
        $textnamef1.Text = 'MIK_Autokontinent.xml'    
        $textnamef2.AutoSize = $True
        $textnamef2.Location = '80, 80'
        $textnamef2.Text = 'MIK_AutoPremium.xml'    
        $textPercent.AutoSize = $True
        $textPercent.Location = '20, 10'
        $textPercent.Text = 'Percent'
        $inputpecentw1.Location = '20, 40'
        $inputpecentw1.Size = '20, 20'

        $inputpecentw2.Location = '20, 80'
        $inputpecentw2.Size = '20, 20'
        $Read.Location = '20,740'
        $Read.Size = '100, 40'
        $Read.Text = 'Прочитать'
        $Read.add_Click($Read_Click)
        $Save.Location = '680,740'
        $Save.Size = '100, 40'
        $Save.Text = 'Сохранить'
        $Save.add_Click($Save_Click)
      return $form1.ShowDialog()
    } #End Function
    chpecent | Out-Null
```

**Example of file MIK_Autokontinent.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FieldConditions Enable="0" Version="1" />
<FieldCostOptions Enabled="1" Version="1">
    <IncreaseCost Enabled="1" Percent="-5" />
</FieldCostOptions>
```

Errors:

```
C: \program> powershell.exe -noexit .\1.ps1 chpercent -Path1 c:\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml -Path2 c:\program\MIK_AutoPremium.xml
Get-Content: Cannot bind the argument to the "Path" parameter because it is an empty string.
C:\program\1.ps1: 20 character: 42+ $inputpecentw1.Text = [xml] (Get-Content $Path1) | ForEach-Object {$ ...+ ~~~~~~+ CategoryInfo: InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException+FullyQualifiedErrorId: ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Get-Content: Cannot bind the argument to the "Path" parameter because it is an empty string.
C:\program\1.ps1: 21 character: 49+ $inputpecentw2.Text = [xml] (Get-Content $ Path2) | ForEach-Obj ...+ ~~~~~~+ CategoryInfo: InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException+FullyQualifiedErrorId: ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentComman
```

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and copy-paste the exact command invocation. There are a lot of spaces within paths, and while this can be the root cause, the error message doesn't quite match. While you are at it, remove redundant Powershell-version tags. Those are meant to be used when a specific version (often old) is required.

Comment: You still have content such as `C: \ program \ 1.ps1` which doesn't look right. Are using whitespace character in directory names? The error says `(Get-Content $ Path1`, but the code says `Get-Content $Path1` (no space after `$`). Unless the error and code match 1:1, trying to debug the issue is quite troublesome.

Comment: powershell.exe -noexit .\1.ps1 chpercent -Path1 c:\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml -Path2 c:\program\MIK_AutoPremium.xml